# how to change title color of toolbar in pre-lollipop versions of Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-5.0-lollipop, android-toolbar

I am learning to design Android apps using new ***Material Design themes***. And while designing a custom *ToolBar* I was trying to give a custom color to the title inside the my custom *ToolBar*. 
On Android Lollipop device it is working fine as expected, as you can see in the image link given below, but when i tried it to run on the pre-Lollipop device, I am not getting the same result. Why so? I have attached the code below.

Here I have attached the screenshot of both, Lollipop version as well as pre-Lollipop version screens.

1. [Lollipop version which shows it correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RKHo.jpg)
2. [pre-Lollipop version which is not giving the expected output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ow5uJ.jpg)

***Code:***

***activity_main.xml***

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        layout="@layout/app_bar" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

***styles.xml***

```
     <resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>


    <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">#455A64</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#607D8B</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">#9E9E9E</item>

    </style>

    <style name="CustomToolbarTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#D32F2F</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#F44336</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

***app_bar.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#1976D2"
android:theme="@style/CustomToolbarTheme"
android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**P.S.: If this Question (or similar) is already been answered here, then please comment the link here. Thank You!**

Comment: While searching out for a plausible solution i found out that I made a mistake while appending my `CustomToolbarTheme` to `app_bar.xml`

Error Lines : `android:theme="@style/CustomToolbarTheme"
android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"`

As it is turned out that pre-Lollipop versions do not understand `andoird:` attr (don't know why, I am naive), thus causing an error.
Though the solution is pretty simple, you need to add there a namespace (eg. app) instead. like:
`app:theme="@style/CustomToolbarTheme"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"`

Sorry for trouble!!!

Comment: It's not that pre-Lollipop versions don't understand `android:` prefix, just `Toolbar` is an element adding as support and because of that its attributes aren't in default define Android namespace. As it is with `Toolbar` and when you are using attributes of your own control or layout, you need to declare and use other namespace, e.g. `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`. Anyway, I'm glad it works!

Comment: overflow icon color is not changing for me in htc pre lollipop device any idea? in lollipop and above devices it is working perfect any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You're using

```
    android:theme="@style/CustomToolbarTheme"
```

which is this:

```
    <style name="CustomToolbarTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#D32F2F</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#F44336</item>
    </style>
```

It's not overriding the colorPrimary attribute like AppTheme.Base is. Add that line to this style and make sure the background is set to it, like this:

```
    <style name="CustomToolbarTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:background">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">#455A64</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#D32F2F</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#F44336</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: it didn't work. Even after that I tried to use a pre-defined theme `android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"` in the `app_bar.xml` instead of `android:theme="@style/CustomToolbarTheme"`.
But still no help :/

Answer (score 1):

Try set `titleTextAppearance` for your `Toolbar`'s theme, like this:

```
<style name="Toolbar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="titleTextAppearance">@style/Toolbar.TitleText</item>
</style>

<style name="Toolbar.TitleText">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/toolbar_title_text</item>
</style>
```

**EDIT:**
Sorry, I forgot to add that you should set one more thing.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        ...
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        app:theme="@style/Toolbar"
        app:titleTextAppearance="?attr/titleTextAppearance"/>
```

(Solution above can be used also for other text appearance's attributes, for example `android:textStyle` or `android:textSize`.)

Comment: thank you for your support. Actually it was a `namesapce` error which was giving headache...check my comment above, I tried to explain it in my words, plz correct it if needed...

Answer (score 1):

if it not working then you can also set toolbar custom title colour and toolbar custom title at runtime. Code snippet is given below

```
private Toolbar toolbar;

            toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
            toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF557F"));
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Title");
```

Comment: how to set overflow icon color?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this:

**color.xml**

```
<resources>

    <color name="white">#fff</color>
    <color name="primary">#673ab7</color>
    <color name="primary_dark">#512da8</color>
    <color name="accent">#ffc400</color>
    <color name="text_primary">#009688</color>
    <color name="text_secondary">#e2eef0</color>

</resources>
```

**values/themes.xml**

```
 <resources>
        <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base"/>

        <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat">        
            <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
            <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
            <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
            <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/text_primary</item>
            <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_secondary</item>
            <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
            <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        </style>

</resources>
```

**values-v21/themes.xml**

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/text_primary</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_secondary</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/primary_dark</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

See some tutorials:

[material-design-everywhere](http://antonioleiva.com/material-design-everywhere/)

[Android L Tutorials (Part 2): Material Theme Colors](http://treyrobinson.net/blog/android-l-tutorials-part-2-material-theme-colors/)

Answer (score 0):

you use this on your theme `android:textColorPrimary` , so instead use this `textColorPrimary` because the first is using just in v-21 on lollipop